# Is there a bounded-quantifier formula in ZF without Foundation that defines the naturals?

Tags: set-theory

Does there exist a first-order set-theoretic formula $\phi(x)$ using only bounded quantifiers such that, in ZF without assuming the Axiom of Foundation/Regularity, $\phi(x)$ is true if & only if $x$ is (the von Neumann construction of) a natural number?  The only predicates for defining the naturals that I can find are variations on $\phi(x) := \forall I(\emptyset\in I \land (\forall y\in I)(y\cup\{y\}\in I) \to x\in I)$ (which isn't bounded) and $\phi(x) := x=\emptyset \lor ((\exists k\in x)(k\cup\{k\}=x) \land (\forall y\in x)(y=\emptyset \lor (\exists k\in x)(k\cup\{k\}=y)))$ (which needs not be satisfied by only the naturals in non-well-founded theories; e.g., the Quine atom satisfies this predicate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this is possible, for the following reason:

The characteristic property of a formula with bounded quantification $\phi(x)$ is that the truth of $\phi(x)$ for some $x$ in a model $M$ depends *only* on how the membership relation behaves on the transitive closure of $x$, not on what is in the rest of the model.

Therefore, if we can find two models $M$ and $N$ of $\text{ZF}-\text{Reg}$ with elements $x\in M$ and $y\in N$ such that $x$ is a natural in $M$ but $y$ is not one in $N$, yet the transitive closures of $x$ in $M$ and $y$ in $N$ are isomorphic, then there cannot exist a bounded-quantifier formula that defines the naturals.

Here's a slightly convoluted way to do that (assuming, of course, that ZF is consistent):

Let $N$ be a model of $\text{ZF}-\text{Reg}$ with Aczel's anti-foundation axiom.

*Inside* $N$, carry out the usual compactness argument that there is a model $M$ of ZF which contains a non-standard integer $x$.

Still working inside $N$, look at the membership structure of the transitive closure of $x$. Because of the anti-foundation axiom, $N$ contains some $y$ whose transitive closure is exactly isomorphic to $x$. But $y$ cannot be a natural in $N$, because $(M,x)$ was *explicitly* constructed such that $x$ would be a *non-standard* natural when seen from $N$.

Now, even though $(M,x)$ was constructed inside $N$, we can easily lift it out of $N$ to become a model that lives in *our* universe side-by-side with $N$. It is still a model of $\text{ZF}-\text{Reg}$ (because everything is first-order, so the conditions for being a model inside $N$ guarantee that the lifted model is a model at our metalevel too), and similarly the *isomorphism* between $\bar x$ and $\bar y$ that exists in $N$ induces an isomorphism at the metalevel. This completes the proof.

Answer (score 2):

*The method below fails because we need at least one unbounded quantifier in order to obtain the power set of $x$, however I am keeping this answer here so that others attempting to solve this problem will have a starting point.*

To define $\omega$ we either need to find a way to express its minimality as an inductive set, or its minimality as an infinite ordinal; or we need to find a way to define a finite ordinal and write $\omega$ as the set of finite ordinals.

- $x$ is transitive, that is **every element of an element of $x$ is also an element of $x$**.
- $x$ is linearly ordered by $\in$, that is **given two distinct elements of $x$, one is the element of the other**.
- $x$ is inductive, that is **the set with no elements is in $x$, and for every $k$, element of $x$, there is another element of $x$ which is equal to $k\cup\{k\}$**.
- $x$ is well-founded, that is **for every element of $\mathcal P(x)$ which is non-empty there is a $\in$-minimal member**.
- $x$ contains only finite sets, that is **every $k$, element of $x$, has the property that every collection of subsets of $k$ is either empty or contains a $\subseteq$-maximal element**.

Note that I use the power set twice, once for well-foundedness and one for finiteness. I also use Tarski's definition of finite (Dedekind's definition would also be applicable and would require quantification over elements of $\mathcal P(x\times x)$, so we use power sets again as well as products).

It should be remarked that finite-ness and well-foundedness are both second-order properties, i.e. there are models of ZF in which there are uncountably many [internally] finite sets. Spooky but true. It seems a bit unlikely to find a way to define them without appealing to unbounded quantifiers, or at least bounding the quantifiers at the power set or so.

Comment: Wouldn't "$x$ is transitive and well-ordered by $\in$" and "$x$ is Dedekind-finite" be enough?

Comment: @Hagen: What about $\omega+1$? :-)

Comment: I meant to formalize "$x\in\omega$ directly, not $x=\omega$, therefore I used "$x$ Dedekind-*finite*".

Comment: @Hagen: Oops! I didn't see... I just woke up and my BAC is still not low enough. :-) Either way, that would define *a* finite ordinal, but not the collection of all finite ordinals.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila. How do you write "$x$ is well-ordered by $\in$" as a bounded formula over ZF-Foundation?

Comment: @Ali: You simply relativize the axiom of foundation to $x$, in that statement all the quantifiers are bounded.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila. I am a bit confused. Let us take the axiom foundation:
$$\forall z [z\neq \emptyset \rightarrow (\exists y\in z) y\cap z=\emptyset]$$
The formula that says "$x$ is well-founded by $\in$" is:
$$(\forall z\subseteq x) [z\neq \emptyset \rightarrow (\exists y\in z) y\cap z=\emptyset]$$
How do you eliminate the $(\forall z\subseteq x)$ at the beginning and get a bounded formula?

Comment: @Ali: $\forall z\in\mathcal P(x)$. **Edit:** Although thinking about it it seems that defining the power set might hide a quantifier.

Comment: "Dedekind-(in)finite" would seem to have a similar problem with expressing using bounded quantifiers only.

Comment: @Henning: Yes, if the power set is the key issue then indeed. Otherwise it's fine. I need to think it over for a bit.

Answer (score 0):

This is too long to write in comments so let me note here that if we can express "$x$ is an ordinal" as a bounded formula $\mbox{ord}(x)$ over ZF-Foundation then we can also express 
"$x$ is a natural number". First define (as in Jech, 3rd ed, p. 164) "$x$ is a limit ordinal" as

$$ \lim(x) \mbox{ iff } \mbox{ord}(x) \wedge (\forall u\in x) (\exists v\in x) u\in v.$$

Now

$$x \mbox{ is a natural number  iff } \mbox{ord}(x) \wedge (\neg \lim(x) \vee x=0) 
\wedge (\forall u\in x) (u=0 \vee \neg\lim(u) ).$$

So if it is the case that "$x$ is a natural number" is not equivalent to a bounded formula over ZF-Foundation then neither
is "$x$ is an ordinal". Since the usual definition of "$x$ is an ordinal" employs "$x$ is well-founded", it also follows 
that "$x$ is well-founded" is not equivalent to a bounded formula over ZF-Foundation.

$$ \mbox{ }$$

**Note**: If the axiom of foundation holds, then it is easy to define "$x$ is an ordinal" as a bounded formula over ZF. There are different ways to do it:
$$\mbox{ord}(x) \:\: \mbox{ iff } \:\: x \mbox{ is a transitive set } \wedge  x \mbox{ is totally ordered by } \in.$$
Or
$$\mbox{ord}(x)  \:\: \mbox{ iff } \:\:  x \mbox{ is a transitive set } \wedge \: \in \! \mbox{ satisfies trichotomy on }x.$$
Or
$$\mbox{ord}(x)  \:\: \mbox{ iff } \:\:  x \mbox{ is a transitive set } \wedge  (\forall u \in x)(u \mbox{ is a transitive set}).$$

The above equivalences are in Kunen 2011, p.34, p.38, p.39.